# regex check if string is a logical expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i want a regex that would check only contains of logical expressions: 0-9 == || != && etc...

this is my try so far:

```
/^([ \-+><0-9])|(&&)|(==)|(\x7C\x7C)|(!=)|(<=)|(>=)$/i
```

Im not sure how it works

http://regex101.com/r/xE4fY3

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: Give example strings.

Comment: I've tested it with strings like `1!=3` and works.

Comment: You're only matching one expression for the whole line, try this: `/^(([ \-+><0-9])|(&&)|(==)|(\x7C\x7C)|(!=)|(<=)|(>=))+$/i`

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/xE4fY3 @AntonioRagagnin look at this

Comment: So you want to match a Number combined with a logical operator and followed by a number? Like `1 != 4` and `4 >= 56` and maybe `6 && 8`?

Comment: I'm a fan of regex101 links, but please give here: example inputs, expected output, actual current output.

Comment: @scragar post your answer, it works

Comment: Is the string: `<0==========` allowed ?

Comment: @user3325976 FYI: it would be a good idea to give an example of your inputs for such questions. That would make it a lot easier to answer your questions in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only matching one expression for the whole line, try this:

```
/^(([ \-+><0-9])|(&&)|(==)|(\x7C\x7C)|(!=)|(<=)|(>=))+$/i
```

Answer (score 2):

I created [this little fella](http://regex101.com/r/oZ1tV2).

```
^\h*(\-?)([0-9]+)\h*(&&|==|\x7C\x7C|!=|<=|>=)\h*([0-9]*)$
```

The `\h*` is optional whitespace (spaces, tabs).

Then, the next/*first* part should be numbes (*right?*).

At least one Number. Optional negative or positive.

Followed by more optional whitespace.

Followed by the optional logical operators.

Followed by a number.

Answer (score 2):

Not so different from Andresch Serj solution, a verbose version ( readable and higthly editable ):

```
$pattern = '~
    # subpattern definitions
    (?(DEFINE)
        (?<operator> && | [!<>=]?= | \x7C\x7C | [+-<>] )
        (?<operand> -?[0-9]+ )
    )

    # main pattern
    ^ \h* \g<operand> \h* (?: \g<operator> \h* \g<operand> )* \h* $
    ~x';
```

Comment: this is goooood... , newer new there exsist verbose regular expressions